# Automatic subdomain wildcard for DHCP-DDNS additions?

Tags: dhcp, bind, wildcard, isc-dhcp, ddns

I'm running dhcp-4.0.2 server and bind-9.6.1-P3.

When a new Mac OSX DHCP client with the name "harry" connects to the network, the DHCP server gives it a lease, and adds appropriate A & PTR records via DDNS. This works fine; harry.my.domain points to (e.g.) 192.168.1.3, the Mac client knows that its name is harry.my.domain, 192.168.1.3 points back to harry.my.domain, and all that is great.

Now I want *.harry.my.domain to resolve to 192.168.1.3, and I don't want to have to go in and add wildcard records into zone files. I want the Mac to connect to the network, and have the hostname and wildcard subdomain resolve to the IP address it's been given.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add (only once) the following record to your BIND zone file:

```
*.harry.my.domain. CNAME harry.my.domain.
```

Comment: Hmm, not sure why I've seen this question in the list of "recently active" :)

Answer (score 0):

It's non-trivial.

You'll need to disable the built-in DDNS stuff and reimplement dynamic DNS on your own, using an "on commit {}" event handler. The "REFERENCE: EVENTS" section of the dhcpd.conf(5) man page points users at a string on line 72 of the source code (server/dhcpd.c) which contains one such handler. It seems to indicate that only *one* handler for each event type can exist.

Unfortunately the handler there is out-of-date and doesn't use RFC-compliant updating, so you'll have to fix that as well. That said, it *may* be as simple as replacing the ns-update() function calls with the newer ddns-update() calls documented in dhcp-eval(5).

If you do get it working, could you post the event handler you end up using with it?